# php search engine with foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql

my search function

```
     <?php
    $i=0;
    $column_name = 'title'; // column to search by
    $k =$_GET['k'];
    $terms = explode(" ",$k);
    //connect before calling mysql_real_escape_string
    mysql_connect("localhost","","");
    mysql_select_db("test");
    $query ="SELECT bookid,title,author 
    FROM  books WHERE";
    foreach ($terms as $each){
        $i++;
        $each = '%' . $each . '%'; // add wildcard
        $each = mysql_real_escape_string($each); // prevent sql injection
        if($i==1)
            $query .= " $column_name LIKE '$each' ";
        else
            $query .= " OR $column_name LIKE '$each' ";

    }

    echo 'QUERY: ' . $query;

    $query = mysql_query($query) OR DIE(mysql_error());

//Code below is for using the relationships table assuming you have a column name id that
//references to the relationships table. Also, you should add a index on the column id.

$results = "";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  $results .= '<li>
                <a href="book-relationships.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['title'].'  author: '.$row['author'].'</a>
              </li>';
}

$results = '<ul>' . $results . '</ul>';

echo $results;
```

i need help linking one database with another when searching, this database is listing all the books that have come up in search, then comparing them with another table called relationships and printing out the titles of books that have a relationship with the book searched.

when the search is run this is what is produced in the browser

```
QUERY: SELECT id,title,author FROM books WHERE title LIKE '%jarrads%' Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'
```

any helpy would be appreciated I'm 100% stuck

schemas

books - bookid, title, author, yearpublished, publisher.....
relationships - relationshipid, bookOne, bookTwo, relationship, relationshiplikes, relationshipdislikes

bookOne and bookTwo, relate to bookid

Comment: Can you update your post with the schema for your books table?

Comment: you need to show us what the database schema for the tables look like.

Comment: can you post columns from your table `books`

Comment: i need to create a page that will spit out the relationships table when bookid=bookOne

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your query, as the error message states :

`Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'`

Check your table `books` for a list of valid fields. One way to achieve this is to run the following query:

`SHOW CREATE TABLE books;`